# Android Dialog with SharedPreferences

Tags: android

If you press a button in my app, a Dialog will show up with some textviews which has to be loaded with text via SharedPreference. But when I want to do this, the app is crashing..

Here's my code:

```
      @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // show up view met medische specialisten

        final Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(Gevaar.this);
        settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogms_layout
                , null));
        settingsDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));




        Button dialogButton = (Button) settingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.terugms);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                settingsDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });






        settingsDialog.show();



        final TextView popuptxt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mspopuptxt1);
        String naamms1 = myPrefs.getString("NAAMMS1", null);
        popuptxt1.setText(naamms1);
```

I've 'designed' the Dialog (of course) in a simple layout.

So what is the problem with my code?

EDIT

Logcat:

```
10-28 18:16:24.940    2239-2239/com.stylo.diabetes E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.stylo.diabetes.Gevaar$10.onClick(Gevaar.java:453)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Just a guess, if your mspopuptxt1 TextView is inside of your dialog, you should call settingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.mspopuptxt1)

Comment: @user2971732 Why not use a Builder for making your dialog?

Comment: Thanks DevrimTuncer! calling the TextView in settingsDialog.findViewById....... Worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
final TextView popuptxt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mspopuptxt1);
```

with this:

```
final TextView popuptxt1 = (TextView) settingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.mspopuptxt1);
```

Because your `mspopuptxt1` `TextView` is inside of your `Dialog`'s content.